# How to do a svn checkout on a single click using wxpython?

Tags: python, svn, wxpython

I need to checkout from SVN when I click on a single button in my GUI. I have developed a GUI using wxpython where I have a submenu called 'svn checkout'. I need to checkout from SVN when someone clicks on that submenu.  I tried the below code which did not work for me.

```
def OnSvnCheckout:
    svn checkout svn://localhost/dev/main 'D:\my project
```

Comment: I'm not a big python user, but does that even compile?  What do you mean by "it did not work"?

Comment: It is just a part of the code where svn checkout happens when user clicks on the button.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to run the svn command in a shell:

```
import os

def OnSvnCheckout(event):
    os.system('svn checkout svn://localhost/dev/main D:\my project')
```

Comment: Thank u Frank Niessink. I tried the other command which worked for me def OnSvnCheckout(self,event):
        Execute(r'%s checkout %s  %s' % (SVN_EXE, REPO_URL, projDir))